# Pass data to a existing form

Tags: c#, forms

I have a program that needs a data from another form and I need to pass it without creating a new instance of the first form. how can i do that?

ex.

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();

f2.showdialog();
```

when f2 shows, their is an listview with items, when I click on an item, I want the item to be sent back to the first form without closing form2 and without instantiating a new Form1.

Comment: You could simply make a public variable `selectedItem` or something in your form2 and assign it on click

Comment: `f2.showdialog();` should be `f2.ShowDialog();`

Answer (score 1):

> I need to pass it without creating a new instance of the first form.

That means you have your first Form open in the background. You can use [`Application.OpenForms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) property to get the already open form and then get the data from there. 
Something like:

```
Form2 f2 = Application.OpenForms["Form2"] as Form2;
if(f2 != null)
   string data = f2.SomeProperty;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for some kind of event.

```
public event EventHandler MyButtonClicked;
```

And before you use ShowDialog();

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.MyButtonClicked += f2_MyButtonClicked;
f2.showdialog();
```

And somewhere to handle the event

```
void f2_MyButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Here you want to grab your list. You can get f2 from sender.
    Form2 f2 = (Form2)sender;

    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

When you in Form2 click the button you raise the event.

```
void myButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MyButtonClicked != null)
    {
        MyButtonClicked(this, new EventArgs()); 
    }
}
```

If you want to read more on events have a look at.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Clear, concise and with an example; I'd upvote more if I could.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps create a mutator(set) method in form1. When you wish to pass data back to form1, call the mutator method to update the form.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to have a publicly accessible method in `Form1` that knows how to handle a new item. Then in `Form2` have a reference to the `Form2` object. Either `Form2` has a Property for that or you set `Form1` as parent `Form2 f2 = new Form2(f1)` (or `this` if you call it from f1).

Now that you have a reference to the `Form1` object, you can call its method to handle the item.