# how to pass datagridview value to another form

Tags: c#, winforms

i am working with my c# windows aplication, in this application form named "patients" and other named "patientsDuplicatedName" which contain datagridview and load all Duplicated Patients Name (this and works fine,,) 
but i want when slsected Row get all values into form "patients" at run time (already open)  without creating new form "Patients"..
Below is the code I am referring to:

```
    public partial class frmPatientsNameDuplicated : Form
{
    PatientFiles frmPatientsFiles =new PatientFiles() ;
    public frmPatientsNameDuplicated()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


   private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       this.Close();
   }

   private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       frmPatientsFiles.txtFileNum.Text = this.dgvPatientsName.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
       frmPatientsFiles.txtArbName.Text = this.dgvPatientsName.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
       frmPatientsFiles.txtEngName.Text = this.dgvPatientsName.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
       //frmPatientsFiles.show();//this line is creating new form and run 
       this.Close();

   }
}
```

sorry about my bad english & thanks in advance

Comment: What you actually need ? You have two forms form1 and form2 .In form2 you loading all duplicated patient names right .! When a row is selected from form2 all the details of that row should be passed to form1 right.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found same issue here :
[Pass data to a existing form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112066/pass-data-to-a-existing-form)
so my code become

```
public partial class frmPatientsNameDuplicated : Form
{
PatientFiles frmPatientsFiles = Application.OpenForms["PatientFiles"] as PatientFiles;
public frmPatientsNameDuplicated()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Close();
}

private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   frmPatientsFiles.txtFileNum.Text = this.dgvPatientsName.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
   frmPatientsFiles.txtArbName.Text = this.dgvPatientsName.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
   frmPatientsFiles.txtEngName.Text = this.dgvPatientsName.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
   this.Close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The commented out line `frmPatientsFiles.show()` has a comment that says that the line is creating a new form.  It is not.  It is simply displaying a form that has been previously created on line `PatientFiles frmPatientsFiles = new PatientFiles();`  This appears to be creating the new form that you don't want.  If you already have an existing form that you want to update, reference that form from your `btnOk_Click` event handler. To do this, you probably want to pass in a reference to the (existing) form to your class, either via the constructor or some other method/property.  I hope I have understood your question correctly.